# Безопасен ли такой игровой сервер Node.js?

Tags: node.js, разработка-игр, socket.io

Технология Socket.io. Сервер при подключении юзера будет брать его параметры из базы и проверять хэш, дальше с базой работа только в исключительных случаях, например изменении параметров важных, но основные параметры (координаты передвижения) будут браться из переменных node.js на сервере, а записываться в базу только при разрыве соединения. Безопасен ли такой сервер? Тем что проверяется хэш только при соединении? Не могут ли подменить в таком случае юзера через сокеты?

Comment: Что есть хэш и откуда он у юзера (или не юзера)?

Comment: в чем безопасность отсутствия записи данных в БД?

Answer (score 2):

Если бы вы делали банковское приложение, я бы сказал, что не безопасно. Потому как теоретически перехватить TCP коннект на каком то из промежуточных маршрутизаторов возможно. Но так заморачиваться из за игрушки вряд ли кто то будет.

Что то мне подсказывает что вы хеш генерите по базе и сверяете с готовым хешем, присланным клиентом. Если он НЕ основан на предварительной отсылке клиенту случайного числа и генерации хеша исходя из данных пользователя и этого числа - то проблем будет больше с ним, чем с перехватом сессий.

Если вы все таки сомневаетесь, предусмотрите в протоколе раз в N минут запрос у клиента нового хеша.

Comment: То есть хотите сказать, что какая-нибудь клиентская игра со вложениями денег и их хранением и оборотом не стоит внимания также, как и банковское ПО?) Кто-то ведь хакает персов, крадет шмотки, а потом перепродает их на аукционах))

Comment: Если есть потенциальный MitM, то проверка этих хешей так же ничего не даст. проще просто сами пакеты шифровать/подписывать, чем обычно занимается SSL и тогда проще использовать его и не парится

Comment: @Mike с целью уменьшения нагрузки и задержек, возможно, стоит ограничиться одним лишь самостоятельным подписыванием пакетов без SSL